# How To Inform OSX Launchpad of a Newly Installed Application with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do I programmatically, like with Objective C, inform the OSX Launchpad application that I have installed a new application in `/Applications`? I'd rather not do the `killall Dock` technique -- that's pretty harsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When copying your `.app` folder into the `/Applications` folder, ensure it's entirely ready. Do not copy an incomplete piece and then copy in other pieces afterwards. So, stage it in `/tmp` or something like that and then move it into `/Applications` afterwards.
2. Your failsafe is this command in Objective C:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] noteFileSystemChanged:@"/Applications"];
```

The Dock application, which is actually the true host of the Launchpad tool (it's part of Dock) will receive notice from that API that the application was installed and will update itself accordingly.